# Explain black height algorithm in Red-Black tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have looked around for a way to check this property of a red black tree: "Every path from a node to a null node must contain the same number of black nodes".

Most of the upvoted answers look like this:

```
// Return the black-height of node x.  If its subtrees do not have
// the same black-height, call attention to it.

private int checkBlackHeight(Node x) {
if (x == null)
  return 0;
else {
  int leftBlackHeight = checkBlackHeight(x.left) +
      (x.left.isBlack() ? 1 : 0);
  int rightBlackHeight = checkBlackHeight(x.right) +
      (x.right.isBlack() ? 1 : 0);
  if (leftBlackHeight != rightBlackHeight)
      complain("blackheight error", x);
  return leftBlackHeight;
  }
}
```

What I am confused about is, doesn't this code only check for the leftmost and rightmost paths down the tree? How does it check for the inner paths?
e.g. In the tree below, it should check the path 11-9-8-.. and 11-16-18... but does it check 11-16-13- (some inner nodes) -...

```
         11
       /    \
      9     16
     / \    /  \
    8  10  13   18
   /\  /\  /\   / \
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code ends up checking all the paths, the way I understand it at least, is because the function has both a "go left" and "go right" instruction, so for each node both left and right are explored, and so all the paths will be covered. Additionally, determining whether the left node is black simply determines whether to add one to the black path length (for each recursive call).

Comment: I kind of see what you mean. Could you explain a little more, in this line for example: `int leftBlackHeight = checkBlackHeight(x.left) + (x.left.isBlack() ? 1 : 0);` the function checkBlackHeight seems to recursively call left child of x until it reaches a null node. The next line isn't executed, until this recursive call is done. How I imagine it is like a wave starting from the root and going down the leftmost path. Similarly, the next line sends another 'wave' down the rightmost path. At which point does it divert and go inside?

Comment: First, it goes down the leftmost path. After it finishes that path, because the function isn't finished until the right call is also performed, the deepest left child node also does its right-sided call (which ends up returning 0 uneventfully until the right child isn't null). In the example you gave, after execution goes down to 8 it will then go to 10, finishing the recursive call from 9, and after that will finally get to 11's right-side recursive call.

Comment: @Van, this answer is correct. I think you need to work on your understanding of recursion a bit.

Comment: @kylew You are absolutely correct. I drew it out and it was easier to understand. Thanks a lot Kyle!

Comment: Glad to help! It can be pretty hard to first grasp concepts like recursion, but it's so nice once you get it! Happy coding! :D

Comment: @ShihabShahriar I think my problem wasn't recursion. It was actually tree traversal. This is very much like a pre-order tree traversal procedure! A Youtube tutorial helped a lot: https://youtube.com/watch?v=gm8DUJJhmY4 . But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Van, "my problem wasn't recursion. It was actually tree traversal" - you wouldn't say this if you really knew recursion. Recursion and tree traversal aren't two distinct concepts, you traverse tree *by* recursion.

Comment: @ShihabShahriar Uhm... Yes, traversing the tree is by recursion, which I DID understand, but what I didn't was how exactly that works in a tree (for example, in the tree above, why is it that after node 8 finishes, the function goes to node 10 and nowhere else). I really appreciate your input, but it didn't help me as much as what Kyle did, which was specifically explaining things out and not just throwing a general comment. However, again, that doesn't mean I don't appreciate your input, so thank you:).